# thread const error C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Could anyone please tell me why this code is producing an error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

void thread_func(const std::map<string, int>& shared) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        if (shared["what"] != 2 || shared["when"] != 4) {
            throw std::logic_error("not read safe");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::map<string, int> shared;
    shared["what"] = 2;
    shared["when"] = 4;

    vector<thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        threads.push_back(thread(thread_func, shared));
    }

    for (auto& th : threads) {
        th.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following error

```
error: passing ‘const std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::basic_string<char>]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         if (shared["what"] != 2 || shared["when"] != 4) {
```

Could someone please guide me in the right direction with this?

Thanks

Comment: Note that the `shared` map isn't very shared at all here: it's copied to each thread. If you really want it to be shared you can wrap the actual argument in a `std::ref` call.

Comment: How is that the case? I am passing it by reference, at least it seems like I am. I guess this is something I do not know much about since I have never actually coded variadic templates..

Comment: The argument to the thread constructor is not passed by reference. So, instead of `threads.push_back(thread(thread_func, shared))`, do `threads.emplace_back(thread_func, ref(shared))`. Disclaimer: not seen by compiler.

Comment: Could you explain why the map is copied though?

Comment: I just did? It's not perfect argument forwarding. The call to your thread function happens a little later, using copies of the supplied arguments.

Comment: See note 3 in [cppreference docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::map::operator[]` can modify the map as it inserts the argument key if not already present and can thus not be invoked on constant objects.

Use `std::map::at()` instead.

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't have a const version though?

Comment: @Aaryaman: it's better that it doesn't - if you had existing code operating on a `const` object and expecting `[]` to `throw` for non-existent keys, then realised you might need to do an `insert` somewhere so modified the object to be non-`const`, you would change the semantic meaning of all the existing uses of `[]`.

Comment: @Aaryaman Because it inserts the key if not found and it would be weird if it would behave differently for `const map`, so they just left it out. (I guess at least, I am not on the committee.)